# Laravel 5.7 Database Relation not Working

Tags: database, laravel, migration

I have two tables in Database.These named as 'Users' & another is 'Discussion.
User's Model is

```
class User extends Authenticatable{

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];


protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function Discussion()
{
    return $this->hasMany('app\Discussion');
}}
```

User Migration Table is:

```
  public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('avatar');
        $table->boolean('admin')->default(0);
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Discusssion Model is:

```
class Discussion extends Model{
protected $fillable = ['title','content', 'slug' ,'user_id', 'channel_id'];

public function Reply()
{
    return $this->hasMany('app\Reply');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('app\User');
}

public function Channel()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('app\Channel');
}}
```

Discussion Migration Table:

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('discussions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('channel_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->text('slug');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

The Controller returning:

```
 public function show($slug)
{

    return view('discussion.show')->with('post',Discussion::where('slug',$slug)->first());

}
```

Now when I am trying to retrive combined data like

```
<h1>$post->user->name</h1>
```

it is showing me

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR) Class 'app\User' not found
```

I am not getting what is the exact problem. Can anybody Help to figure out the problem please ?

Comment: The error is pretty self explanitory, your User model must be in a different namespace.  if you `use` your User class at the top you could change the relation function to this `return $this->belongsTo(User::class);` rather than write plain text. then your IDE would highlight this error.

Comment: You need to capitalize ‘app’ to be ‘App\(model)’. Capitalization matters in namespacing. You could also do what Jeff mentioned above and use the (model)::class method since your models already are in the App namespace (providing you haven’t changed it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide a listing of the records within the "discussions" and "users" tables? Also, double check your class reference in the Discussion model.  I would guess you want "App" to be upper cased instead of "app\User".  Unless you purposefully changed the App namespace, it is initially set up with a capital "A" by default.